# Plotting a 4 axis graph with a variable in each axis

Tags: r, function, axis-labels, gplots

I´m looking to make a graph that looks like this:

[image: specific factors model]

in R.

The basic idea is to have a variable on each axis and graph the interactions between those variables, is there any way to connect the axis of different plots, or to do a single graph like this?

If there is of any use, these are the functions I want to plot:

```
fq11 <- function(q21){3.42-0.75*q21}
fq21 <- function(q11){3.33-0.67*q11}

gq12 <- function(q22){2.08-1.75*q22}
gq22 <- function(q12){1.67-1.33*q12}

hq11 <- function(q12){4-q12}

jq21 <- function(q22){3-q22}
```

For context, each letter represents the quadrant where the functions interact, only in f and g 2 functions interact.

Answer (score 1):

You can put them all on one graph, but I don't know what you want to do with the functions you've provided. What limits do you want on the axes? Which four of the 6 functions do you want in which of the four quadrants?

I plotted them all to see if there might be some pattern you were trying to make, but nothing stuck out to me. They're all straight lines...

In lieu of the unknowns, I've provided an example of how you could do this so that perhaps you'll either be able to run with this or you'll understand what else I might need to know to help further.

In this example, I've shaded II and III. I've plotted four functions, one in each of the four quadrants. I used base R plots here, but this can be done with `ggplot`, as well.

```
circ1 = function(x){
  sqrt(10^2 - x^2)
}
circ2 = function(x){
  -sqrt(10^2 - x^2)
}
circ3 = function(x){
  sqrt(9^2 - x^2)
}
circ4 = function(x){
  -sqrt(9^2 - x^2)
}

plot(x = NULL, y = NULL, xlim = c(-10, 10), ylim = c(-10, 10))
curve(circ1, from = 0, to = 10, add = TRUE)
curve(circ2, from = -10, to = 0, add = TRUE)
curve(circ3, from = -10, to = 0, add = TRUE)
curve(circ4, from = 0, to = 10, add = TRUE)
polygon(c(0, -10, -10, 0), c(0, 0, -10, -10), 
        col = scales::alpha('darkgreen', 0.2))
polygon(c(0, 10, 10, 0), c(0, 0, 10, 10), col = scales::alpha('darkgreen', 0.2))
```

[image]